# Use JMeter to accept Aysnc Response From Server

Tags: jmeter

I have an application that will provide async response when asked a question like "How are you?"

My application will say "I am good" after some time.

I can provide the URL in my initial question which can be used to reach JMeter.  But how do I get JMeter to accept the response?

Here is what my request look like:

```
  "conversation": {
    "id": "111"  // unique id for each conversation
  },
  "serviceUrl": "http://localhost:54673" // the callback url for response
  "text": "How are you?"
```

Here is where the response will be posted to:

```
  Response URL:  http://localhost:50643/v3/conversations/111/activities
```

And here is the content:

```
{
  "type": "message",
  "conversation": {
    "id": "111"
  },
  "text": "I am good"
}
```

This response is async so it's a new connection.  How do I setup JMeter to do this?  And what would be the Response URL for me to send msg to?

Comment: do I understand correctly: after some time server sends POST request to the client (with the answer)?
if so, unfortunately there's no such sampler. You will have to either use programmable element (e.g. JSR223) or (better) develop a custom Java sampler. Unless someone can recommend a plug-in.

Comment: Yes, you understand me perfectly.  I am trying to get it to accept incoming new connections.  To do POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to use JMeter the only way I can think of is querying the `Response URL` in a loop using [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) until you get a response or timeout occurs.

However from request and response types it appears you're trying to test a [Microsoft Bot Framework](https://dev.botframework.com/) based application so it would make more sense to consider [Visual Studio Load Testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/load-test/getting-started-with-performance-testing) tools for this. Check out [BOT Testing with VSTS](https://github.com/thirumathi/bottestvsts) sampler project for more details. You can also find [MockChannel](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Samples/tree/master/blog-samples/CSharp/MockChannel) example useful.

Comment: You are correct, I am trying to test a bot framework.  I will check that out!

Comment: If I use the MockChannel, how do I test how long the response take?  I would need to capture the response to be able to measure it.